# Python image recognition with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

When I try to recognize an image with `pyautogui` it just says: `None`

```
import pyautogui
s = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Dark.png')
print s
```

When I ran this code the picture was on my screen but it still failed.

Answer (score 5):

It's pixel perfect.

It can't find the image if it is not 100% match.

For example, I cropped an area with an Opera extension. Then I ran my script with Firefox, and pyautogui did not recognize it.

1. Don't let your image get resized or compressed by screen capture software or extensions.
2. Use the same window/screen (size, resolution) as where you saved your screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Pyautogui.locateOnScreen has a parameter that specifies the 'confidence' you have in the image you enter.

This way, pyautogui will deal with slight pixel deviations.

For example:

```
import pyautogui
s = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Dark.png', confidence=0.9)
print(s)
```

For more information, see *https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyautogui/latest/pyautogui.pdf*.

Comment: Just a note. For confidence keyword argument to work, you need to install opencv-python package: `pip install opencv-python"

Answer (score 3):

On my system, I get this if the picture is on a second monitor. If I move it to the main screen, the image is located successfully.

It looks like multiple-monitor functionality is not yet implemented:
From http://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/roadmap.html

> Future features planned (specific versions not planned yet):
>
> - Find a list of all windows and their captions.
> - Click coordinates relative to a window, instead of the entire screen.
> - Make it easier to work on systems with multiple monitors.
> - ...